# phpMyAdmin is available on all apache domains

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin

I have the domain name `example.com`.

I create `example.com` and `staff.example.com` which redirect both on same apache server, but on two different VirtualHost.

Now, I install phpmyadmin on my server, but i can access to it thanks to `example.com/phpmyadmin` AND `staff.example.com/phpmyadmin`, but i want to make it accessible only on the second domain name.

How can i do ? (On linux, Ubuntu)

Comment: Are you using Linux or Windows?

Comment: I'm on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: Oh, alright, I will post an answer. Please wait a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `apt` provided phpMyAdmin package. I suggest you to manually install it because you will have more control over it and you can do whatever you want.

Enable the extensions mbstring and zip by running `sudo apt install php-mbstring php-zip -y && sudo phpenmod mbstring zip`

> Thanks to @Elikill58 for pointing out, download the version of phpMyAdmin that corresponds to your PHP version.

Go to https://www.phpmyadmin.net, download phpMyAdmin (zip).

> Replace `<version>` with your phpMyAdmin version you've downloaded.

Extract the phpMyAdmin by using the command `unzip phpMyAdmin-<version>-all-languages.zip`

Move the extracted folder to the web root of staff.example.com by doing `sudo mv phpMyAdmin-<version>-all-languages /path/to/web/phpMyAdmin`

Go to the web root of staff.example.com.

Then go to the phpMyAdmin folder by `cd phpMyAdmin`

Then run `sudo mkdir tmp && sudo chmod 777 tmp`.

Run `sudo apt install pwgen -y` for generating a blowfish hash, and then run `pwgen -s 32 1` and copy the random set of characters displayed.

Run `cp config.sample.inc.php config.inc.php` and edit config.inc.php with your preferred editor.

Change the line like:

```
. . .
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = ''; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */
. . .
```

To:

```
. . .
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'STRINGOFTHIRTYTWORANDOMCHARACTERS'; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */
. . .
```

(Change STRINGOFTHIRTYTWORANDOMCHARACTERS to the random set of characters you got by running the command `pwgen -s 32 1`.

> If you have the same directory for example.com and staff.example.com:
>  
>   Inside the phpMyAdmin folder, create a .htaccess file and add the following contents to it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !staff.example.com$
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Hopefully this works.

Comment: Also, restart apache after doing these things.

Comment: Thanks you, it works ! Just, for other people who will try this:
Choose the version of phpmyadmin which correspond to your php version (else you will get some problem)

Comment: @Elikill58 You are welcome. You are right about the version.

Comment: @Elikill58, I am just curious, were staff.example.com and example.com hosted from the same folder?

Comment: No, for me, example.com is on /var/www/html and staff.example.com is on /var/www/staff .